# NSNotificationCenter to refresh data not moving past addObserver

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, nsnotificationcenter

I need to use `NSNotificationCenter` to update me when new data comes in from `WCSession` so I can fill out my `tableview`.

I'm setting breakpoints at each of the functions listed, but for some reason it **goes right to** `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:", name:"load", object: nil)` and **then no where else**.

So something isn't right, can you help me out?  Thanks!

**`DataManager`:**

```
class DataManager : NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let tColorValue = userInfo["TeamColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Matchup"] as? String {

            receivedData.append(["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue])
            evnts.append(Evnt(dataDictionary: ["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue]))
            self.dataObjects = evnts
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)

        } else {
            print("not same as dictionary value")
        }

    }
```

**`InterfaceController`:**

```
override init() {
        super.init()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:", name:"load", object: nil)
}

func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    //load table data here
    doTable()
}

func doTable() {      
    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(DataManager.sharedInstance.dataObjects.count, withRowType: "rows")

    for (index, evt) in DataManager.sharedInstance.dataObjects.enumerate() {

        if let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TableRowController {
            row.mLabel.setText(evt.eventMatch)
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It appears that `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` is not being called. Can you show where in your code you use `DataManager`?

Comment: I agree with @thislooksfun, How are you sending data through the WCSession?

Comment: @thislooksfun yeah thats what seems to be happening.  I have the `DataManager` usage in `doTable()` posted above, but let me know if you're talking about something else and I'm missing what you're saying.  Will post anything extra as needed, thanks!

Comment: @KyleRedfearn my process (which must be wrong) is: (`DataManager.swift`)-> get the data in `WCSession` -> use `NSNotificationCenter` to fire a notification that data has been received with `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)` -> (`InterfaceController.swift`) -> listen and receive notification that data has loaded from `DataManager` with `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:", name:"load", object: nil)` which calls... -> `loadList:` which just runs `doTable` -> `doTable` loads up the table.

Comment: You have the right process, but needs some items added before it. Send the data to the watch from your app via the WCSession API

Comment: I thought I was already sending the data to the watch from my app via the `WCSession` API?  Both the `ExtensionDelegate` and `InterfaceController` code I listed above are in my Watch App you know?  So the `WCSession` code I have is where the Watch gets the data from the main app.  What part am I missing that you're talking about specifically, I can't quite seem to understand, but I know I'm missing something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**DataManager:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil, userInfo: [String : AnyObject])
```

**InterfaceController:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doThisWhenNotify(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
//........


func doThisWhenNotify(notification : NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo
    //load your stuff here
}
```